# php show data in textarea after link has been pressed

Tags: php, codeigniter, textarea

How can i display data in a textarea after a link has been pressed?
This data is saved in a database.

I'm trying to dynamically create a link for the field 'date'. If a user presses the link, the rest of the data for that date should be shown in a textarea.

i'm looping through my data like this:

```
foreach($data as $key)
{
    echo '<a href="/"' . $key->test . '>' . $key->date. '</a>';
    echo '<br />';
}
```

I dont know what i should be putting in 'a href'.

So to be clear, on the left side i got a few links which represent date's. On the right side i want to display a textarea which will contain the remaining data.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See the working demo here.](http://jsbin.com/odiho4)

Modify your loop like this:

```
foreach($data as $key)
{
    echo '<a class="link" href="#"' . $key->test . '>' . $key->date. '</a>';
    echo '<br />';
}
```

And then you can use this jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
  $('a.link').live('click', function(){
    $('#textarea_id').val($(this).text());
    return false;
  });
});
```

Where `textarea_id'` is the id of your textarea in which you want to update the values of links eg:

```
<textarea id="textarea_id">............
```

**Update:**

To add the above script, put this code between `<head></head>` tags eg:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascrpt" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascrpt">
    $(function(){
      $('a.link').live('click', function(){
        $('#textarea_id').val($(this).text());
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: How do i add this script in a php file?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery you could do something like:

```
$('a.dates').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevents link from reloading page
    $('input#date').val($(this).attr('title'));
})

<?php
    foreach($data as $key)
    {
        echo '<a class="dates" title="$key->date" href="">' . $key->date. '</a>';
        echo '<br />';
    }
?>

<input id="date" value="" name="date" />
```

Comment: That won't work for dynamic links and he doesn't have title any way :)

Comment: Seeing as he generates the links using PHP .click should work just fine. And what does it matter if he didn't have a title, he can add it just like we both had him add a class to the link.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways: dynamic and non-dynamic (normal). Lets start with the second one.

When someone clicks on a link it redirects him to your PHP file. Lets see an example:

```
//in HTML
<a href="index.php?action=getcontent&date=03022010" id="d03022010">Show details for date 03.02.2010</a>
//and so on..

//PHP
if($_GET['action'] == "getcontent"){
  $date = $_GET['date'];
  //connect to DB and retrieve data to e.g. $result
}

//your textarea
<textarea><?php echo $result; ?></textarea>
```

In dynamic way, you have to use Javascript (or some Javascript libraries, like jQuery) to download data after user's click on a link and update `textarea` element. Example jQuery (I didn't test it...)

```
//HTML head section
<script type=text/javascript>
  $('#d03022010').click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'url/to/php',
      data: {date: 'your_data'},
      dataType: 'text', //or html or json
      success: function(result){ $(textarea).text(result)}
    });
  });
</script>
```

Hope this is helpful.